# Как узнать, с какого адреса пришел request?

Tags: python, django

Собственно, пишу свою функцию приёма платежа с `webmoney-merchant`. Надо сделать проверку, действительно ли полученный запрос пришел с `webmoney`. Как это осуществить?

Comment: так там же подпись надо проверять, если подпись совпадает - значит либо с webmoney запрос пришел, либо вы как-то секретным ключом со всеми поделились

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Только не ограничивайтесь одной этой проверкой

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
if referer and (urlparse(referer).netloc == webmoney_domain):
    #запрос пришёл с webmoney
    ...
```